# Memory leak C++ string

Tags: c++, string

I have a class eg

```
class test{

   public:
      somedatahere
      test();
     ~test();
   private:
       string mystring;

}
```

In this class the constructor reads the contents of a file in variable mystring.My question is :

Does mystring gets freed when the class destructs or I must free it manually? How can I free mystring ?

Comment: You don't have to free it. You probably don't even need to write a destructor at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `mystring` is part of the object, it will go out of scope when the object does. There's no need to "manually" free it, and indeed you can't.

This would be different if `mystring` was a pointer to memory allocated with `new` (or `new[]`), then you'd have to manually `delete` (or `delete[]`) it from your destructor.

Answer (score 5):

You only have to free what you allocate. `new` should be matched by `delete`, and `new[]` matched by `delete[]`.

If you don't do either, then a well-behaved class shouldn't require you to do the other.
And yes, the standard library is well-behaved.

So no, you don't need to do anything. Let the `std::string` instance clean up after itself. (And of course, follow its example, and ensure that your own classes do the same)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your constructor just assigns directly into `mystring` without any other allocation or doing something weird, then yes it will be deallocated properly by the destructor.